# Amazon Cognito Authenticated User with Auth0

Tags: authentication, amazon-web-services, xamarin, amazon-cognito, auth0

I've been trying to use the authenticated code provided from Auth0 and AWS Cognito to authenticate a user but when I go to the AWS Cognito Console dashboard I see no identities have been created.
Logic flow should be this:  I get my JWT from Auth0 when a user logs in and I use that to get my AWS Cognito Credentials - I use the following code:

```
CognitoAWSCredentials credentials = new CognitoAWSCredentials (
"us-east-1:11047a24-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-111111111", // Identity Pool ID
Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1); // Region


credentials.AddLogin("stef.auth0.com", id_token1);  //id_token1 from Auth0
```

I did input the JWT (id_token1) into jwt.io to check the validity of it and it comes back VALID SIGNATURE when I add the Auth0 Client Secret.  I am not able to see any errors when I run the code.  I am using Xamarin C#.  I did all the necessary setup with configuring the provider, setting up the default IAM roles for Cognito Auth/UnAuth.  Put in the correct Auth0 client ID into AWS, etc...  I can however add an Unauthenticated user but not an Authenticated user.

Am I using the wrong code here?  Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thank you for looking!

Comment: Read some post about how Amazon does not accept HS256 and only RS256.  I have changed the signature on Auth0 to RS256 and plugged it into jwt.io but I'm still getting an invalid signature.  I am still unsuccessful with authenticating a user...  The post is located here:  [link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=171711)

Comment: You said you are getting an error. Can you post the full error and the code where you are getting the error?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am not getting any kind of error - It just won't create an Authenticated Identity Id when I use the above code (It won't return anything in the output that indicates an error.).  When I input the AUTH0 JWT in JWT.IO website debugger I get an Invalid Signature.  What I noticed is that when I erase the Key Id value in the header it gives back a Valid Signature.  Any thoughts on this?  I have been following this procedure here:  [Auth0-Cognito](https://auth0.com/docs/scenarios/amazon-cognito)

Comment: Maybe Amazon isn't doing the following from the procedure:  "Amazon will use the public signing key from the OpenID Provider Metadata (https://subscription.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json) to validate the signature of the JSON Web Token."